# Как подключить библиотеку в js через терминал?

Tags: javascript, библиотека

Возникла проблема при подключение библиотек JavaScript в Atom.

Посмотрел что на сайте есть вот такая команда 'npm install --save rgbaster'.
И как я понял, библиотеку нужно устанавливать через терминал.

Через Sublime Text 3 я не в какую не смог загрузить даже терминал.
Скачал Atom, установил терминал, и все равно происходят ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а у вас нода вообще установлена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы можете работать с любого терминала, не обязательно с редактором кода. Откройте cmd или Ваш терминал и наберите команду

   node -v

Должен показать вашу версию, вот например как у меня -

```
v14.16.0
```

Если такого не произошло и выдало ошибку, то Вам нужно установить node js из официального сайта, после этого установиться сразу и npm.

2. Если не установлен node, то как я понимаю, не инициализирован проект npm.
   Зайдите в директорию вашего проекта и инициализируйте его

   npm init

Ввести имя проекта, автора и т.д.

```
package name: (trash)
version: (1.0.0)
description:
entry point: (index.js)
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
```

Появиться package.json. Это нужно для управления настройками проекта, запуск, тест, форматирование кода, билд и т.д

3. После этого мы можем устанавливать зависимости

   npm install --save rgbaster

Вместе с ним можно установить webpack и так же его настроить

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
```

Далее заходите на официальный сайт webpack и настраиваете webpack.config.js

4. После настройки, Вы можете сделать билд вашего проекта -

   npm run build